# What is this insect I found in Russia?

Tags: zoology, entomology, species-identification

I found this in Russia. It is approximately 2cm long.

[image: unidentified insect photo 1]

[image: unidentified insect photo 2]

Comment: What area of Russia? it is a large country so that could be a good clue to rule some options out.

Comment: @GriffinEvo, Volga Region. However I think it is an international insect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a wasp, (see that nice slim "wasp waist" it's got?), which means taxonomically that it is in the order Hymenoptera (which it shares with bees and ants).

Within Hymenoptera, wasps are diverse and often difficult to ID, but it's possible that this is a Braconid or Ichneumon (family Braconidae or Ichneumonidae). If you take a good closeup of its wing veins, chances are an expert (not me) could ID it.

Comment: I'd agree it's definitely a kind of parasitic wasp - I'd be inclined towards the Anomaloninae subfamily - perhaps get in touch with the Russian Entomological Society 

http://www.zin.ru/societies/res/index_en.html also http://www.opsu.edu/Academics/SciMathNurs/NaturalScience/PlantsInsectsOfGoodwell/ichneumonidae/default.html and 

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomaloninae

Comment: The [ichneumon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ichneumonoidea) wasps I've seen all have long ovipositors not seen here, so I doubt it's one of those.

Answer (score 2):

Since it got bumped and no one seemed to be too clear on an identification. Based on the presence of two recurrent veins in the forewing, following identification guidelines [here](http://jenny.tfrec.wsu.edu/opm/displaySpecies.php?pn=920), I'd identify the above wasp to be a member of *Ichneumonidae*. The identification of the subfamily, however, is difficult without access to the wasp itself for close observation. *Ctenopelmatinae* is a good candidate in my opinion, however, due to the close morphological features, and the geographic distribution of many genera tends to be holarctic.